# Are there any equivalents to the futex in Linux/Unix?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I'm looking for something could be used for *polling* (like `select`, `kqueue`, `epoll` i.e. not *busy polling*) in C/C++. In other word, I need to block a thread, and then wake it up in another thread  with **as little overhead as possible**.

A `mutex` + `condition variable` works, but there is a lot of overhead. A `futex` also works, but that's for Linux only (or maybe not?). Extra synchronization is not required as long as the *polling* itself works properly, e.g. no race when I call `wait` and `wake` in two threads.

Edit: If such a "facility" doesn't exist in FreeBSD, how to create one with C++11 built-in types and system calls?

Edit2: Since this question is migrated to SO, I'd like to make it more general (not for FreeBSD only)

Comment: Do you also need to block on _multiple_ sources, or just one? `select`, `poll` etc. are normally used for (de)multiplexing multiple fds, not just blocking on one.

Comment: @Useless One is good enough. Your are right, `select` is not a good example here. I mentioned it just to illustrate I don't want *busy waiting*

Comment: After the migration I;m confused about the 'target' for this question. Are you looking for the answer to be for FreeBSD, POSIX, or standard C++11?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm using FreeBSD which has POSIX and C++11. So I'm open all those three options

Comment: @GuLearn Were you able to find something for this?

Answer (score 3):

You want semaphores and not mutexes for the signaling between the to threads..

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html

Semaphores can be used like a counter such as if you have a queue, you increment (post) to the semaphore every time you insert a message, and your receiver decrement (wait) on the semaphore for every message it takes out.   If the counter reach zero the receiver will block until something is posted.

So a typical pattern is to combine a mutex and a semaphore like;

```
sender:
    mutex.lock
    insert message in shared queue
    mutex.unlock
    semaphore.post

receiver:
    semaphore.wait
    mutex.lock
    dequeue message from shared structure
    mutex.unlock
```

Answer (score 3):

semaphores are not mutexes, and would work with slightly less overhead (avoiding the mutex+condvar re-lock, for example)

Note that since any solution where a thread sleeps until woken will involve a kernel syscall, it still isn't *cheap*. Assuming x86_64 glibc and the FreeBSD libc are both reasonable implementations, the unavoidable cost seems to be:

1. user-mode synchronisation of the count (with a CAS or similar)
2. kernel management of the wait queue and thread sleep/wait

I assume the mutex + condvar overhead you're worried about is the cond_wait->re-lock->unlock sequence, which is indeed avoided here.

Comment: I'm okay with the syscall and context switch because I have a lot of not-that-busy threads. My concern about semaphore is that it may be even less efficient than `mutex` + `condition variable`: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sema&sektion=9. The `man sem_overview` in Ubuntu didn't say anything about performance though. I may need to compare that myself.

Comment: The glibc source for x86 shows it implements semaphores using the futex syscall to manage waiters, and a userspace CAS for the counter (eg. [this pseudocode](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/DESIGN-sem.txt;hb=HEAD)). I don't know how much cheaper it could be, but you'll need to investigate behaviour on other platforms yourself.

Comment: The [FreeBSD libc code](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/gen/sem_new.c?view=markup&pathrev=232144) looks similar ...

Comment: `sem_t` seems to be faster than `std::mutex + std::condition_variable` when the contention is low.